# Single Sign On

Tags: asp.net

Do we need to use out proc sessions while implementing SSO?What will be the limitation of inproc?
which is best way of implementing SSO across domain?

Answer (score 1):

The use of inproc session vs. persisted session has little to do with SSO. The main limitation of inproc sessions is that it won't work in a loadbalanced setup, but again, it has little to do with SSO. The easiest way to implement SSO is to use the [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx), which is part of .net framework 4.0 (there is also a version that works with .net 3.5).
Basically you just implement [a passive STS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872350.aspx). There are several walkthroughs out there.

Comment: I need to implement in ASP.net 2.0.

Comment: yeah that sucks. :) Your best bet would be a ASMX web service (intermediary server). Both domains would 'talk' to this web service to perform the SSO. And only this web service would deal with the session.

Answer (score 0):

If both of these applications are using forms authentication then the solution is easy. All you have to do is configure the machineKey on both applications to be identical and set the domain on the forms cookie to be .exampledomain.com for both web.configs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom authentication scheme built around session variables, you might want to consider configuring both servers to point to the same SQL Session State database. If you go this route, you can modify the GetTempAppID to always return 1 and configure the machineKey on both applications to be identical. Just another suggestion from your friendly sheero. HOI!

Answer (score 0):

inproc sessions will be an issue if your application is running behind the load balancers, so you might want to think about SQL server based sessions, plus you also need to think about if you really need a usual SSO that just keeps you automatically logged in, like if your user has different rights/permission set on different sites then you might want to add some custom code in your SSO login piece, as you have mentioned that you are using ASP.Net 2.0 so i am assuming you might be using the .Net role based profiles for group security and permissions, so you also might want to check if you get your self in a scenario where your logged-in user has different permission set in your different sites. So for me its not just SSO its custom login code for a specific requirement you might want to look into.